# Automating Python Task

Tags: python, testing, optimization, automation, jupyter-notebook

I would like to automate the below python code to be applied to different dataframes.

```
df_twitter = pd.read_csv('merged_watsonTwitter.csv')
df_original = pd.read_csv('merged_watsonOriginal.csv')

sample_1_twitter = df_twitter['ID_A'] == "08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd"
sample_1_twitter = df_twitter[sample_1_twitter]

sample_1_original = df_original['ID_B'] == "08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd"
sample_1_original = df_original[sample_1_original]

sample_1_twit_trunc = sample_1_twitter[['raw_score_parent_A','raw_score_child_A']]
sample_1_ori_trunc = sample_1_original[['raw_score_parent_B','raw_score_child_B']]

sample_1_twit_trunc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
sample_1_ori_trunc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

sample_1 = pd.concat([sample_1_twit_trunc, sample_1_ori_trunc], axis=1)
sample_1['ID'] = '08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd'

stats.ttest_rel(sample_1['raw_score_child_B'], sample_1['raw_score_child_A'])
```

For example, the above code that indicates the ID "08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd" is of a specific individual. If I am to calculate the T-test for all the samples I have, then I'll need to keep replacing the different ID's for everyone by copying and pasting it on the code above.

Is there a method to automate this process whereby these sections;

```
df_twitter['ID_A'] == "08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd"
df_original['ID_B'] == "08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd"
sample_1['ID'] = '08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd'
```

could accept all the ID's I have and automate the entire process.

At the end, save each result output generated by this function as well:

```
stats.ttest_rel(sample_1['raw_score_child_B'], sample_1['raw_score_child_A'])
```

Comment: Write a function with the changing values as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus mentioned you need a function which takes arguments. You can just try to place your code in a function. You may want to store your ID's in a list of any iterable collection. You can also store the t-test results in a list.

```
    ids = ["08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542fd","08b56ebc-8eae-41b3-9c86-c79e3be542f4"]

    def runTTest (id,df_twitter,df_original):
        sample_1_twitter = df_twitter['ID_A'] == id
        sample_1_twitter = df_twitter[sample_1_twitter]

        sample_1_original = df_original['ID_B'] == id
        sample_1_original = df_original[sample_1_original]

        sample_1_twit_trunc = 
        sample_1_twitter[['raw_score_parent_A','raw_score_child_A']]
        sample_1_ori_trunc = 
        sample_1_original[['raw_score_parent_B','raw_score_child_B']]

        sample_1_twit_trunc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        sample_1_ori_trunc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        sample_1 = pd.concat([sample_1_twit_trunc, sample_1_ori_trunc], axis=1)
        sample_1['ID'] = id

        return stats.ttest_rel(sample_1['raw_score_child_B'], sample_1['raw_score_child_A'])

    t_test_results=[]
    for id in ids:
        t_test_results.append(runTTest(id,df_twitter ,df_original))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working perfectly well, if the "ids" variable have a listed set of IDs placed inside it as a list. Is there a method whereby I can use a reference variable that would be able to call all the CSV files placed in a specific folder and process it using this runTTest function all at once ?

Comment: If i correct in understanding. You want to run this on more than 2 csv files? And run the t test for more than 2 groups?

Comment: Exactly, I have around a few hundred CSV files, where all the files start with the "ID" as its naming convention.